# Cannot compile bitcoind with zmq enabled

Tags: bitcoind, zeromq

I need bitcoind with enabled zmq. When I'm building bitocind from source and make ./configure the output is:

`Options used to compile and link:
...
  with zmq      = no
...`

No matter what i pass to arguments.

My configure command looks like:

`$ ./configure --enable-cxx --disable-shared --with-pic --without-gui --with-zmq --enable-zmq --prefix=/home/ubuntu/bitcoin/db4/`

Answer (score 6):

This will happen when you try to build with ZMQ support even though the required libraries are not on your system. In this case, configure will silently turn off ZMQ support, and you should see a line like

configure: WARNING: libzmq version 4.x or greater not found, disabling

in the output. When you install the required version of the ZMQ library on your distribution (make sure to pick the DEV version to get the header files as well), it should work.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks a lot.
`$ sudo apt install libzmq3-dev`
now zmq      = yes

Comment: For homebrew: `$ brew install zeromq`